# expose-loader doesn't expose modifications to exposed object

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

I'm using Webpack 2, Bootstrap 3, and TypeScript, and attempting to integrate npm and packaged bundles into an existing application. I'm using `ProvidePlugin` to make jQuery available, and `expose-loader` to expose jQuery to external dependencies.

(Any combination of `(<any> global).$ = global.jQuery = $;` or webpack`module: { rules [{}] }` configurations wouldn't work, but eventually I got the following to work:

```
plugins: ([
    // make sure we allow any jquery usages outside of our webpack modules
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        jquery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.$": "jquery"
    }),
]),
```

entry.ts:

```
import "expose-loader?$!jquery"
import "expose-loader?jQuery!jquery"
```

However, when I then try and call `import "bootstrap"` I can call `$(...).popover()` within my module, and I can call `$(...)` or `jQuery(...)` outside the module, but I can't call `$(...).popover` outside the module, instead I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

**How do I make methods that are added to jQuery (like the bootstrap `popover` method) available in the global scope, outside of my modules?**

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue:
`PluginProvider` was exposing a different version of jQuery to the application than `expose-loader` was exposing. Bootstrap was initializing on the PluginProvider jQuery, but a different instance of jQuery was being exposed to the `window`.

**So to make it work, delete PluginProvider** and just use the `expose-loader`. And manually import jQuery where you need it as a side-effect of losing PluginProvider.